# What is the difference between ifstream operator>> and get() method?

Tags: c++, fstream, binaryfiles, ifstream

Recently, I have used the `>>` operator when reading binary files, but in some cases it would just skip a byte. It caused me a lot of problems to find where the mistake is in my code, but finally I have managed to fix this with the `get()` method, but I still don't know why `>>` was skipping bytes from time to time.

The goal is to load the first byte from a file into `m_Value`, which is `uint8_t`.

Code with `>>`:

```
bool CByte :: load ( ifstream & fin)
{
    if(! ( fin >> m_Value ) ) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Code with `get()`:

```
bool CByte :: load ( ifstream & fin)
{
    char c = 0;
    if(! ( fin . get ( c ) ) ) return false;
    m_Value = static_cast <uint8_t> (c);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The formatted extraction operator, `>>`, is for reading text. It's not meant for arbitrary binary data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator>>` is a [formatted input function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction) and `get()` is an [unformatted input function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction).

The important difference is, formatted input will skip whitespace<sup>1</sup> before extracting, and it will *parse* data. It's meant to extract text or numbers from a stream, not to read binary data.

---

<sup>1</sup> unless explicitly configured otherwise, with `std::noskipws`